# set const member value from subclass

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

Code:

```
struct A{
    const bool const_some_write_once_flag;
    A(): const_some_write_once_flag(false) { }
};
struct B: public A{
    B(): const_some_write_once_flag(true) { }
};
```

the error is: class ‘B’ does not have any field named ‘const_some_write_once_flag’. I believe that it's because while being in the constructor of `B`, the object being created is not yet of type `A`, because the "inherited slice" of `A` has not yet been initialized.

I've tried several workarounds with no luck, and I'll omit them here. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In its initializer list,`B` can only initialize its own data members, its direct base classes, and any virtual base classes.  `const_some_write_once_flag` is none of these; it is a data member of `A`.  It can only be initialized by a constructor of `A`.

```
struct A{
    const bool const_some_write_once_flag;
    A(): const_some_write_once_flag(false) { }

protected:
    A(bool flag) : const_some_write_once_flag(flag) { }
};
struct B: public A{
    B(): A(true) { }
};
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'd prefer not to have a second constructor, because in the default constructor there will be some initialization code that I don't want to copy-paste to the subclass.

Comment: Nevermind, I saw just now your explanation of why it's impossible.

Comment: Don't copy-paste the initialization; put it in a separate private init() routine, called by both constructors.

Comment: In most cases, I don't think a separate initialization method is useful.  If your class has many constructors (or many member variables that need explicit initialization), the design should probably be rethought.

Answer (score 0):

The following achieves nearly what you're trying to do.  It does create a protected member of A that any other class that chooses to inherit from A can use, though.  You could be even more protective and make B a friend of A and then make the constructor that takes a parameter private.

```
class A{
    public:
        const bool const_some_write_once_flag;
        A(): const_some_write_once_flag(false) { }
    protected:
        A( const bool initialValue ): const_some_write_once_flag( initialValue ) {}
};

class B: public A{
    public:
        B(): A(true) { }
};
```